# Create box that allows draggable elements to be dropped in it using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a website that allows the user to drag text into boxes. I would like the user to have the option to create more boxes using a button which they can drag more text into.

The issue I am having is that I cannot get the button to create a box that allows elements to be dropped in it.

I have pasted the basics of what I am trying to do here http://jsbin.com/vedapu/3/edit?html,css,js,output .

The code below shows the code I have written to create a div when the button is clicked.

```
document.getElementById("text").onclick = function() {
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.ondrop = "drop(event)";
 div.ondragover = "allowDrop(event)";
 div.className = "box";
 document.getElementsByClassName('section1')[0].appendChild(div);
}
```

How can I pass the drop and allow drop to the new div?

Comment: There's a jQuery UI function for this specifically. https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! Change these two lines, which set string values to `ondrop` and `ondragover`:

```
 div.ondrop = "drop(event)";
 div.ondragover = "allowDrop(event)";
```

...to this, which sets the functions instead:

```
 div.ondrop = drop;
 div.ondragover = allowDrop;
```

The event object will be automatically included as the first function parameter.